# JSON path parsing - object vs array

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

```
var sample1 = {
  "book" : {
    "name" : "book 1",
    "type" : "type 1"
  }
}

var sample2 = {
  "book" : [{
      "name" : "book 1",
      "type" : "type 1"
    }, {
      "name" : "book 2",
      "type" : "type 2"
    }, {
      "name" : "book 1",
      "type" : "type 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can any one help me to construct a single JSON path to extract the book name for which the type = "type 1" from both the samples? The problem is the book can be an array or an object but I can have only one json path to extract the value. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using this node module for parsing - https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath

Answer (score 0):

A function with a logical loop would probably work:

```
function getBooks(type, object) {
    var response = [];

    for (var key in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //If its an object, another for-in loop
            if (typeof object[key] == object) {
                for (var k in object[key]) {
                    if (object[key].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                        if (object[key][k].type == type) {
                            response.push(object[key][k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            //If array, a normal for loop will do
            } else if (typeof object[key] == array) {
                for (var i = 0; i < object[key].length; i++) {
                    if (object[key][i].type == type) {
                        responses.push(object[key][i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

You should now be able to pass in either object (with an array of books or objects of books) and a `type` to match on and get an array of matching objects back. This is untested, so bear with me.

Edit: `object` was also a terrible naming choice for that parameter, change that to `bookObject` or something!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified s3u/JSONPath module to be able to apply constraints to individual objects, not only to array elements. With that modification you can get what you're asking for with this single path : 
"$.book[?(@.type=='type 1')]"

Here is the modification for the jsonpath.js:

```
JSONPath.prototype._walk = function (loc, expr, val, path, f) {
    var i, n, m;

    if (!Array.isArray(val)) {
        //make it array of one element, so that @ filters can be applied to non-arrays
        val = [val];
    }

    for (i = 0, n = val.length; i < n; i++) {
          f(i, loc, expr, val, path);
    }

};
```

I did not commit it yet, it should probably be voted for by the contributors to that project, but feel free to do that.

I use that modified module in my projects, and it allows me to write filter expressions that are more to the spirit of JSONPath.